# Does CKEditor have a setting to inform the server of its use?

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a setting in CKEditor that has it add a hidden input field saying something like `"ckeditor" = "1"`?

Basically I want to detect (server side) when it's used and when it isn't.  I can obviously do this with javascript, but I figured if an "official" method existed, that I'd try to make use of it first.

I've been searching through Google and the CKEditor docs, with no luck.  Just wanted to make sure I haven't missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any such setting (I don't really know how it can be useful, but that's not the question).

You should do it with a little javascript that creates or changes a hidden input.

Comment: Needed for when input originates from a client that doesnt support ckeditor. (ipad)